# How to get all message's body by thread_id?

Tags: android, sms, android-contentprovider

I have an activity that shows my inbox this activity has a listview and an OnItemClickListener on it, when I click each item a new acticity starts: I want to show all messages of the contact that I click on it here is part of my code for this activity:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_conversation);
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String value = null;
    if (extras != null) {
        value = extras.getString("id");
    }
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/conversations/");
    Cursor smsCur = contentResolver.query(uri, null, "thread_id=" + value, null, null);
```

now I want to get all messages by thread_id that I have gotten from previous activity but I don't know how? My question is how to get message bodies? there are many question on this topic but I find nothing about how to query message body!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get all messages of a conversation by thread_id, so I can just get messages between two and not other messages:

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
 cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, "thread_id=" + value, null, "date asc");
```

there is a column named "type" that shows whether the message is incoming or outgoing so incoming messages show part of conversation that belongs to a contact and outgoing messages show my part of conversation, I think it is an efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to fetch conversation.

To fetch sent messages

```
Uri mSmsinboxQueryUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
```

To fetch inbox messages

```
Uri mSmsinboxQueryUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
```

For SMS-MMS both:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/");
```

Below code to read message

```
Cursor cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(mSmsinboxQueryUri,new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date","body", "type" }, null, null, null);
String[] columns = new String[] { "address", "person", "date", "body","type" };
if (cursor1.getCount() > 0) {
   String count = Integer.toString(cursor1.getCount());
   while (cursor1.moveToNext()){
       String address = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[0]));
       String name = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[1]));
       String date = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[2]));
       String msg = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[3]));
       String type = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[4]));
    }
}
```

**References**

- http://pulse7.net/android/read-sms-message-inbox-sent-draft-android/
- http://javapapers.com/android/android-receive-sms-tutorial/

Comment: but I want to read all messages between me and a contact that I clicked, I mean for spessial thread_id I think your code is reading all the messages

Comment: I have seen this code many times but I don't want to get sent and received messages separated

Comment: why don't you try to provide condition which you have provided in your question with this answer? Won't this make any difference?